# JavaScript: unexpected output by console.log('str' + int + int)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Refer to the code here below:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var file = 'test.js';
var search = new RegExp("\n", "g");

function printLineNum(err, fileContents) {
    if (err) return console.error(err.message);
    console.log("Total line(s) of document: %d", fileContents.match(search).length + 1);
}

fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', printLineNum);

// output: Total line(s) of document: 10
```

This is a working piece of code. But before I made the changes, line 7 looks like:

```
console.log("Total line(s) of document: " + fileContents.match(search).length + 1);
// output: 91
```

The unexpected error also can be solve by adding parenthesis to the *numbers*:

```
console.log("Total line(s) of document: " + (fileContents.match(search).length + 1));
// output: 10
```

I know how to avoid the error but I can't figure out what's wrong exactly. Is this a JavaScript thing or something to do with `console.log`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
console.log("Total line(s) of document: " + fileContents.match(search).length + 1);
```

In this instance the concatenation operator takes precedence over the  addition operator and is evaluated first.

The statement will be evaluated like:

```
// string concatenation happens first
console.log((("string" + 9) + 1));
// resulting in more string concatenation 
console.log(("string9" + 1));
console.log("string91");
```

Comment: "The concatenation operator has a higher precedence then the addition operator" - this is not correct. Try `1+2+"x"`.

Answer (score 4):

This is due to the fact that the `+` operator is overloaded to perform both addition and string concatenation in JavaScript. If the type of either operand is a string then concatenation takes precedence.

This is described [in the spec](https://es5.github.io/#x11.6.1):

> The addition operator either performs string concatenation or numeric addition.
>
> The production AdditiveExpression : AdditiveExpression + MultiplicativeExpression is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let lref be the result of evaluating AdditiveExpression.
> 2. Let lval be GetValue(lref).
> 3. Let rref be the result of evaluating MultiplicativeExpression.
> 4. Let rval be GetValue(rref).
> 5. Let lprim be ToPrimitive(lval).
> 6. Let rprim be ToPrimitive(rval).
> 7. If Type(lprim) is String or Type(rprim) is String, then
>
>    1. Return the String that is the result of concatenating ToString(lprim) followed by ToString(rprim)
> 8. Return the result of applying the addition operation to ToNumber(lprim) and ToNumber(rprim). See the Note below 11.6.3.